# is Stanford OpenIE available for Chinese text?

Tags: stanford-nlp

All,

My understanding is Open IE analysis is NOT yet available for Chinese text, based on the [information here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html).

However, from this [demo site](http://corenlp.run/), I used a simple Chinese sentence, "鲁迅住在上海" (LuXun lives in Shanghai), it returns Open IE result:

[image]

Can someone tell me if Open IE is available for Chinese text now?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no Chinese model for OpenIE.  I am not sure what would happen if you ran the English model on Chinese text.

Comment: that is what I thought. However, from the demo site (corenlp.run), I entered that small example, selected chinese... and it shown a OpenIE result as I shown above.

Comment: I mean apparently it will return a result, but I'm not sure that the results will be any good...I suppose it's possible to the extent it is just looking at the dependency parse maybe it will do something semi-reasonable?

Comment: it does not consistently return a result ... so I guess it is likely at a experiment stage. Or, as you have said, looking a the dependency and coming up with something. anyway, thanks!